# How can I replace a group of letters between to symbols using Python and regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use Python and regex to replace any number of words / spaces in a string between two %  % symbols with '_____' to create a gapfill from a string like this one:
**input_string = "it's not easy to find a  % tailor % =(person who makes suits)"** 
 
 the resulting output should look like this...
**"it's not easy to find a  % _____ % =(person who makes suits)"**

Note, I need the % to remain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with the following pattern:

```
import re
re.sub(r'(?<=%).*?(?=%)','_____', input_string)
# "it's not easy to find a %_____% =(person who makes suits)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with regex `lookahead` and `lookbehind` to replace the text between two `%` characters. `re.sub()` is your friend here

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=%)([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)(?=%)"

test_str = "it's not easy to find a % tailor % =(person who makes suits)"

subst = "_____"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://rextester.com/NRHMW81828

Answer (score 1):

```
**Juste Use :**
import re
input_string = "it's not easy to find a % tailor % =(person who makes suits)"
input_replace = re.sub('(?<=%).*?(?=%)', "'____'", input_string)
print(input_replace)

**OutPut:**
it's not easy to find a %'____'% =(person who makes suits)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the example I can see that you want to keep space at the beginning and end of word:

```
import re
input_string = "it's not easy to find a % verylongtailor % =(person who makes suits)"
print(re.sub(r'(?<=%)(\s*)(.+?)(\s*)(?=%)', r'\1____\3', input_string))

# if you want to keep the same length of the word
print(re.sub(r'(?<=%)(\s*)(.+?)(\s*)(?=%)', lambda m: '{}{}{}'.format(m.group(1), '_' * len(m.group(2)), m.group(3)), input_string))
```

OUTPUT:

```
it's not easy to find a % ____ % =(person who makes suits)
it's not easy to find a % ______________ % =(person who makes suits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `re.sub`:

```py
import re

input_str = "it's not easy to find a % _____ % = (person who makes a % _____ % suits)"
placeholder_re = r'\%([^\%]+)\%'
replacement_str = 'lorem ipsum'
output_str = re.sub(placeholder_re, replacement_str, input_str)
print(output_str)
```